# How to convert a folder of xml docbook files to reST?

Tags: pandoc, restructuredtext, docbook

Using pandoc, it is easy to convert an xml docbook file to reST (rESTRUCTUREDTEXT) using the command:

```
pandoc -f docbook -t rst path_to_xml_file
```

Is it possible to convert a whole folder of xml docbook files to reST using pandoc ?

Comment: yes, simply specify `path/to/files/*` (when using linux or mac)

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple shell script within directory with your docbook `.xml` files:

```
for FILENAME in *.xml; do pandoc -f docbook -t rst -o "${FILENAME/.xml/.rst}" "$FILENAME"; done
```

**Note:** I assumed your docbook files have `.xml` extension.